# Figure subtitle

Tags: captions

I am trying to add a little figure caption underneath some of my graphics for aesthetic purposes (the title in the graphics themselves are much too small).

I'm looking for it to look something like this:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}


\begin{document}


{\centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Screen_Shot_2018-05-04_at_10_18_47_AM}\par}

%TABLE:
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table}
    \raggedright
%\centering
Firm Performance, 2010-2017

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{Annual Return} 

                                                                \\
    \midrule
N   &  12,727        &         \\
Mean (\% Change)

            & 25.29   &     \\
    \addlinespace
Median   & 19.48             &             \\
Min & -92.86   &    \\
Max & 851.01   &    \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note: I included the table just so that we will have some context/can make it work in a fluid manner.

Any help is appreciated! Here is how it currently looks by the way:

[image]

Comment: use a figure environment and a \caption like you used table and \caption.

Comment: Note, you can put tabulars in figures and images in tables and text in both.  The only difference is in how \caption behaves.

Comment: This looks like a nicely formulated task, but I don't see any problem, let alone an actual question here.